# Jquery event on Combo open

Tags: jquery, combobox

I want to load the content of a combo when it is opened everytime. so I added the code as below:

```
$("#CustomerCombo").on("click", function (e) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CustomerMaster.aspx/GetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            CustomerLoad(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) { }
    });
})

function CustomerLoad(data) {
    $("#CustomerCombo").empty();
    $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value="0">--- Select Customer ---</option>');
    for (var i in data) {
        $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value=' + data[i].CusId + ' id=' + data[i].CusId + '>' + data[i].CusName + '</option>');
    }
}
```

First I thought its working fine. But when ever I try to select a customer from the combo it gets refresh itself.

How do I call event only when the combo opens and not when a customer is selected?

**Update:**

My Html code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="lblCategory">Customer</label>
    <select class="form-control mandatory lblSelectCC" id="CustomerCombo">
         <option value="0">--- Select Customer Category ---</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

on Page load too I am calling the ajax:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

     $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CustomerMaster.aspx/GetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            CustomerLoad(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) { }
    });


    // other codes
});
```

Actually I need something like **[this](https://www.bootply.com/n28Db6WWa5)**.

But I can not make it work with my code.

Comment: Why do you need to populate it on click event?

Comment: bcz, when someone enter somedata in all other fields and then they try to select customer, and find out that the required customer is not there, so they go to customer page and create a customer, but to take effect i need to refresh trhe combo and not the whole page

Comment: Then it would be better to populate on  other fields change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have added a new answer. Custom open event

```js
    var json = [{ CusId: 1, CusName: "abc" }, { CusId: 2, CusName: "xyz" }];


    $('#CustomerCombo').data('open', false);
    $('#CustomerCombo').click(function () {
        if ($('#CustomerCombo').data('open') == false) {
            $('#CustomerCombo').data('open', true);
            console.log("refereshed")
            CustomerLoad(json);
        } else {
            $('#CustomerCombo').data('open', false);
        }
    });

    function CustomerLoad(data) {
        $("#CustomerCombo").empty();
        $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value="0">--- Select Customer ---</option>');
        for (var i in data) {
            $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value=' + data[i].CusId + ' id=' + data[i].CusId + '>' + data[i].CusName + '</option>');
        }
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="lblCategory">Customer</label>
    <select class="form-control mandatory lblSelectCC" id="CustomerCombo">
        <option value="0">--- Select Customer Category ---</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your on click function you can check if your CustomerCombo has children. If yes then return if no then do the ajax call.

```
$("#CustomerCombo").on("click", function (e) {
   if ( $(this).has('option').length > 0 ) {
     return;
   }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CustomerMaster.aspx/GetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            CustomerLoad(data.d);
        },
        error: function (msg) { }
    });
})
```

Comment: This will not help me

Comment: when someone enter somedata in all other fields and then they try to select customer, and find out that the required customer is not there, so they go to customer page and create a customer, but to take effect i need to refresh trhe combo and not the whole page

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.off()` or `.one()`

```
$("#CustomerCombo").one("click", function (e) {
    //alternatively use .off() here...
    //$(this).off(e);  //same as using .one()
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "CustomerMaster.aspx/GetCustomer",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
        CustomerLoad(data.d);
    },
    error: function (msg) { }
    });
})

function CustomerLoad(data) {
    $("#CustomerCombo").empty();
    $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value="0">--- Select Customer ---</option>');
    for (var i in data) {
        $("#CustomerCombo").append('<option value=' + data[i].CusId + ' id=' + 
data[i].CusId + '>' + data[i].CusName + '</option>');
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would it need to be called more than once ?